# Arraylist retrieved from populated hashmap keeps returning an empty arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap and I am inserting an arraylist as the value in a while loop. During an iteration, if the hashmap already contains a key, I want to retreive the arraylist already stored, append new data to it and put it back into the hashmap.

The issue I have now is when I check if a hashmap contains a value and it does, the arraylist being returned is of size 0 as though I never put in anything before.

```
final HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
String status = "";
String channel = "";

while (daily.next()) {
    while (avrg.next())
        if (avrg.getString(1).equals(daily.getString(1)) && avrg.getString(2).equals(daily.getString(2))) {
            final Object pstmnt = null;
            final Object pstmnt2 = null;
            final float thresholdValue = calcThreshold(pstmnt, pstmnt2, daily.getString(1));
            channel = daily.getString("client_name");
            if (daily.getFloat(3) > avrg.getFloat(3) + thresholdValue * avrg.getFloat(3)) {
                status = "HIGHER";
            }
            else if (daily.getFloat(3) < avrg.getFloat(3) - thresholdValue * avrg.getFloat(3)) {
                status = "LOWER";
            }
            else {
                status = "Normal";
            }
            final PrintStream out;
            out.println(channel);
            out.println(thresholdValue);
            out.println(status);
            if (map.containsKey(channel)) {
                out.println("map contained key");
                final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                temp.addAll(map.get(channel));
                out.println("previous size: " + temp.size());

                temp.add(daily.getString("event"));
                temp.add(Float.toString(daily.getFloat(3)));
                temp.add(Float.toString(avrg.getFloat(3)));
                temp.add(Float.toString(thresholdValue * 100));
                temp.add(status);
                out.println("current size: " + temp.size());
                map.put(channel, temp);
                out.println("array added to map");
                temp.clear();
                System.out.println("done");

            }

            else {
                final ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
                out.println("new key created");
                temp.add(daily.getString("event"));
                temp.add(Float.toString(daily.getFloat(3)));
                temp.add(Float.toString(avrg.getFloat(3)));
                temp.add(Float.toString(thresholdValue * 100));
                temp.add(status);

                System.out.println(temp.size());
                map.put(channel, temp);
                System.out.println("array added to map");
            }
        }
    avrg.beforeFirst();
}
```

I am really not sure why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you see when you try to debug your program in a debugger?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
map.put(channel, temp);
out.println("array added to map");
temp.clear();
```

`temp.clear()` clears the same list that you've just added to the map. Since `temp` is about to go out of scope, that statement serves no useful purpose and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! That fixed it!!! I want to know though, why did temp.clear() affect the arraylist I inserted? Afterall the clear statement was called after I had inserted the arraylist into the hashmap

Comment: @user1192724: `map.put()` doesn't copy the data; it inserts the same reference as `temp`. So if you change the contents of the `temp` list post-insertion, the changes get reflected in the map.

Comment: Oh I see...That's very useful information. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that @aix has the correct answer, but you should rewrite you code to get rid of all the duplication.  The if block starting from
`if (map.containsKey(channel))`

can be simplified to the following.

```
ArrayList<String> temp = map.get(channel);

if (temp == null) {
   out.println("new key created");
   ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
   map.put(channel, temp);
}

temp.add(daily.getString("event"));
temp.add(Float.toString(daily.getFloat(3)));
temp.add(Float.toString(avrg.getFloat(3)));
temp.add(Float.toString(thresholdValue * 100));
temp.add(status);
```

There is no need to create a new list and copy every time you add to it.